# Freeswitch 1.8 and playback of tone_stream

Tags: voip, freeswitch

I have an example dialplan in a form of:

```
<include>
    <context name="application">
        <extension name="play tone">
            <condition>
                <action application="log" data="INFO *****Playing tone1***** "/>
                <action application="answer"/>
                <action application="sleep" data="1000"/>
                <action application="playback" data="tone_stream://%(1850,4150,475,425);loops=-1" />
                <action application="hangup"/>
            </condition>
        </extension>
    </context>
</include>
```

This bit works with Freeswitch 1.4 but is not working with Freeswitch 1.8, I am getting debug output like this:

```
2019-05-29 11:14:59.971372 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7291 Channel sofia/sip-profile/447872019798@127.0.0.1:5062 entering state [ready][200]
EXECUTE sofia/sip-profile/447872019798@127.0.0.1:5062 sleep(1000)
EXECUTE sofia/sip-profile/447872019798@127.0.0.1:5062 playback(tone_stream://%(1850,4150,475,425);loops=-1)
2019-05-29 11:15:00.971418 [ERR] switch_core_file.c:304 Invalid file format [tone_stream] for [%(1850,4150,475,425);loops=-1]!
EXECUTE sofia/sip-profile/447872019798@127.0.0.1:5062 hangup()
```

I have consulted documentation:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_tone_stream
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Tone_stream

Not sure what to think and not sure where to look for some answers. Is it my configuration somewhere that disables tone_streams? Is it a bug in the new version?

For any hint or outright solution I would be grateful.